# Python AWS boto3 returning NoneType Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm trying to enumerate some EC2 instance details in an AWS account using the boto3 Python module, but I keep getting an unexpected error. Specifically, I'm trying to get the tags associated with each instance.
Here is a rough copy of my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import boto3
import botocore

boto3_session = create_boto3_session(profile_name='some_profile')
ec2_resource = boto3_session.resource("ec2", region_name='some_region')
ec2_instances = ec2_resource.instances.all()
for ec2_instance in ec2_instances:
    tags = getattr(ec2_instance, 'tags', [])
    for tag in tags:
        print(tag)
```

When the code runs, it prints the tags of the instances as expected - until it finds an instance without tags, and then I get the error:

```
    for tag in tags:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

What I don't understand is why the getattr() function returns a 'NoneType', instead of an empty list like I've asked it to. Am I missing something?

Comment: It's probably because your default value is also an empty value. Can you try `None` instead of `[]` as a default value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found the answer. It's not specific to boto3.

When you call `getattr()` on an object, it only seems to return a supplied, default value if the class doesn't have a `__getattr__()` method implemented. If it does have that method, then it will return the value specified in `__getattr__()`, regardless.

This also seems to be the case for calling `hasattr()` on an object. It will return the value specified in `__getattr__()` if the method is implemented. This is somewhat counter-intuitive, because if the `__getattr__()` method is set to return `False`, then
calling `hasattr()` for a non-existent attribute will return `True`.

Comment: So, what is returned when `getattr()` is called above in case of no tags?

Comment: After some more thought, this is perfectly logical, though somewhat counter-intuitive. When I use the ```getattr()``` function, I'm testing if the class has that attribute defined and NOT if that attribute has a value, hence the confusion. So ```getattr()``` always returns a value for ec2_instance.tags because tags is a valid attribute for an ec2_instance. But if there are no tags set, the value of the attribute can be ```None```.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work? All my instances have tags, but I think if no tags exist, you get an empty list, so you may have to check on length if an error pops up.

```
for ec2_instance in ec2_instances:
    if ec2_instance.tags:
        for tag in ec2_instance.tags:
            print(tag)
```

Comment: I think this would give the same error, as sometimes my instances don't have tags. So I'd be trying to loop over a ```NoneType``` in that scenario. The way I've gotten around it is to simply use a ```try``` ```except TypeError```. Which seems nasty, but it works.

Comment: i started an instance without tags and add  if ec2_instance.tags and it works with or without tags. It did have NoneType, but the if statement cures that.